# Automate the boring stuff collatz Sequence

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a python3.3 program (using windows 10 and a notepad and command line) that takes a user input number and outputs a new number each time the output number is not 1, and which changes the number using only divide by 2 for even numbers and multiply by 3 and plus one for odd numbers.

```
def collatz():
    if collatz() == ' ': #if collatz() doesn't have a return value yet
        number = input('Please Enter A Number. ')
    number = int(number)
    if number % 2 == 0:
        number = number // 2
        return number
    else:
        number = 3*number + 1
        return number

while number > 1:
    collatz()
```

I moved things around a bunch, and I have gotten it to repeat the first operation in a loop, and I've gotten it to give me just the one number and then a prompt for more user input? Can somebody tell me how to

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have most of the pieces but not quite in the correct order.  I'm guessing you want something more like:

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        number = number // 2
    else:
        number = 3 * number + 1
    return number

my_number = int(input('Please Enter A Number: '))

print(my_number)

while my_number > 1:
    my_number = collatz(my_number)
    print(my_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a function `collatz()` that accepts a number as an argument to it, and returns a different number, after 1 iteration. You don't usually want to use `input()` inside of a function, because then the function is no longer reusable.

Consider the following code:

```
def func(var):
    print(var)

func(45)
```

It outputs the number 45, as the integer 45 is passed into the function `func()` and can then be used by commands inside `func()`. It then ceases to exist when `func()` has finished. You will probably want to be passing an integer into your `collatz()` function in a similar way.

The following snippet demonstrates using the `return` keyword:

```
def func():
    return 5

var = func()
print(var)
```

This code will print the number 5, as `func()` returns a 5, and it is saved into `var`.

You will want to use both these techniques in your code, so that you take the input from the user outside of the function, then keep on calling `collatz()` on the number, passing the output of it into it the next iteration, until it outputs 1.

I haven't written the complete code for you; you should be able to do that yourself, but let me know if you're struggling.